# Setting camera focus mode in iOS to manual or macro

Tags: ios, ios5, camera

I tried to find information if its possible to adjust camera focus in iOS. In android its possible with adjusting camera parameters to e.g. [FOCUS_MODE_MACRO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_MACRO). Is there anything similar in iphones/ipads. I want to make focus fixed (without auto) and focus in close captures (macro mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (In particular the "focus mode" property).  If that doesn't satisfy your requirement then I don't think anything will.

Answer (score 0):

yes iOS does have a MACRO mode have a look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwaqF.jpg)

Just in case someone is trying to achieve lock on zoom factor just like a native camera one can use the below API.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3875310-setprimaryconstituentdeviceswitc/

```
videoCaptureDevice.videoZoomFactor = videoZoomFactor
videoCaptureDevice.setPrimaryConstituentDeviceSwitchingBehavior(.locked, restrictedSwitchingBehaviorConditions: [])
```